# How come the DJI Fly App is NOT in Google Play Store?

Tags: dji-mini-2

Just got a DJI Mini 2, and followed the instructions to get it up and flying, but the required DJI Fly App was not in Google Play Store. I downloaded it, installed it, and successfully flew with it. The path to follow this type of install is not for your typical end user. Any reason to support the required sideloading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither Google nor DJI have specified the precise reasons why DJI chose to remove their apps from Google Play store.  The nearest we have to an official response from either side has come from the DJI Support Twitter account, and a reply posted to a service announcement on the DJI forum.

The standard response from the DJI Support Twitter account has been:

> We apologize for the inconvenience. Because the compatibility strategy between the DJI App and Google Play Store is changing, you currently cannot finish downloading and updating using Google Play. Thank you for your understanding.

They do not specify exactly what the issue with their "compatibility strategy" is, but it appears that his has been the standard response since their [Tweet on 13 December 2021](https://twitter.com/DJISupport/status/1470305900132913152).

The same statement was [still being used on 10 May 2022](https://twitter.com/DJISupport/status/1524046572065280000))

---

On 14 March 2022, DJI Support posted a service announcement on [Updating Channels for DJI apps (for Android Users)](https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=261363&extra=page%3D1).  On 29 April 2022, an admin [replied to a user question](https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=261363&page=1#pid2731093) by stating:

> Hi, there. The update channels for DJI apps have been adjusted due to Google Play technical adjustments. Please download the latest version of DJI Go 4 from our official website to check if the problem persists.

Again, the precise "technical adjustments" that led to DJI removing their apps from the Play Store weren't specified.  It may indeed be the result of [Google requiring new apps, published after August 2021, to use the AAB (Android App Bundle) framework](https://www.wired.com/story/google-app-play-store-changes-apk-aab/), rather than the traditional APK (Android Application Package) format.  However, until or unless DJI choose to explain their reasons this will remain speculation.

It is worth noting that, although the AAB standard is open source, it is not presently clear whether other portals (like *Amazon App Store*, for example) support the framework.  If they do not, then developers like DJI would either need to publish two versions of their Android apps or withdraw their apps from some portals.

---

In any event, for now the only way for DJI owners to get the Android app is to side-load by following the instructions in the service announcement on [Updating Channels for DJI apps (for Android Users)](https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=261363&extra=page%3D1).

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an authoritative source for this answer, but if [this article](https://dronedj.com/2021/01/27/latest-dji-fly-android-app-only-available-from-djis-website-not-the-play-store/) is to be believed, it's due to a semi-recent technical policy change instituted by Google for apps released on the Play store: (*emphasis mine*)

> Google announced a while back that app developers will have to ensure their *apps are packaged as bundles (AAB) rather than the standard APK*. According to a DroneDJ reader, DJI’s SDK has a *bug that prevents it from compiling* in this new AAB standard.

Assuming this is correct, DJI may just be taking a while to patch the offending software compilation bug preventing the app from being listed on the Play Store. This also explains why, as you mention, a functional version of the app can still be downloaded/installed [from DJI's own website](https://www.dji.com/downloads/djiapp/dji-fly) in `*.apk` form.

Comment: And, there's no version on Play? Seems sloppy to me

Comment: No, it's not that. The version of the app they currently have made is incompatible with the Google Play store's recent rule change(s).

Comment: This feels like half of the truth. There are plenty of apk apps on Play. Usually, Google enforces new rules only for new apps (targeting the updated version of Android/API), but allows support of old API for legacy apps. Fly is not that new and doesn't _have_ to be treated as such. On the other hand, it's a big app and [size matters](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/), so there may be more intricate reasons I don't know...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly DJI Fly is an evolution of DJI Go 4. According to this [news article](https://www.androidauthority.com/dji-go-4-app-security-privacy-issues-1141232/) that app was investigated by some researchers who found things that are not allowed by google policies (anymore?):

> "One of the more suspicious aspects of the app is that it can install
> any application on the user’s device through either a self-update
> feature or a dedicated installer provided by China’s Weibo social
> media giant. Both could download code from outside of the Play Store,
> an aspect of their design that directly violates Google’s policies."

The article was then updated to say that it was not as bad as it seemed.

Maybe DJI Fly suffers from the same issues?!

Answer (score 0):

Nope looks like DJI app has significant security risks and on top of requesting more  user information then the app requires hence Google won't allow it to protect their android users privacy and security.

Comment: Hello! On this site, we value the accuracy of information. Could you please provide some reliable source(s) to back up your answer?

Comment: Are you serious??? Learn to read code yourself, then look at what theyre accessing, then read their terms of use policy. It's clear as day

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps consider editing your answer to cite the code and explain how it violates the Play Store's policy on privacy and why this might result in it being removed from the store. An answer should provide all the information necessary to reasonably back up a claim.

Comment: Here are some more specific reasons. I only use the app on my old Pixel 3 without a sim card and behind my pi.hole DNS filter. https://www.bitdefender.com/blog/hotforsecurity/popular-chinese-drone-android-app-suffers-major-security-issues-investigation-finds/